# Does marking a GameObject as static actually improve performance?

Tags: unity, performance

I'm currently working on a small game that will include somewhat large levels. Each level will have a somewhat large amount of `GameObject`s lying around as props. I was told by a friend of mine that marking the `GameObject`s that the map is comprised of as static will improve performance. However, I am aware that this can greatly increase the amount of space the built game takes up on the disk. Does the performance boost gained from marking `GameObject`s as static outweigh the cost of increased build size? Is there even a performance increase at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely maybe; this depends on things like the overall number and complexity of the objects involved.

**Not static:**

Draw a 100-vertex model with 1,000 different (constantly-changing) transforms.

- Approximately 17,200 bytes (1,200 bytes uploaded once)
- New transforms uploaded every frame (approximately 16,000 bytes)
- More objects creates more overhead (during render), linearly
- Additional math every frame (transforming normals for lighting, etc.)

**Static:**

Since this object won't move ever, copy and transform the 100 vertices, 1000 times, into a single vertex buffer. Then, draw the new 100,000-vertex model with one transform. Multiple draw calls may be required to process the entire model but will require few state changes in-between. Since it's already in world-space, the GPU can skip a transform; the normals are already in world-space, for lighting, as well.

- Approximately 1,200,000 bytes (uploaded once)
- Performance penalty, once, during baking
- More objects creates "no" additional overhead (during render)

**Vertex:**

The "vertex" I used is a single `float3` each; if we also include UV's (`float2`) and normals (`float3`), the size of each vertex becomes 32 bytes:

The non-static method's memory footprint increases from 17.2KB to 19.2KB (1.1X).

The static method's memory footprint increases from 1.2MB to 3.2MB (2.6X).

The memory size of an additional, non-static, object is 64 bytes for a float4x4 matrix. The actual size Unity uses may be different, but the important point is that it is approximately fixed.

The memory size of an additional, static, object is (VertexCount x VertexSize). This method is not feasible for excessively complex and/or numerous objects.